# Seeding the Fortuna PRNG for the first time

Tags: random-number-generator, fortuna

I am trying to understand how the [Fortuna PRNG](https://www.schneier.com/academic/paperfiles/fortuna.pdf) should be seeded correctly for the first time.

Let's assume that we do have a large-enough seed file available, but not any entropy sources during first boot. To my understanding, I would:

- initialize the PRNG (section 9.5.4)
- load the seed file (section 9.6.2)
- produce random numbers (section 9.5.5)

The last step would produce an error: the check on the end of the pseudo-code in section 9.5.5 would assert that `ReseedCnt` is zero: PRNG not seeded yet.

When I track the usage of `ReseedCnt`, I observe the following:

- `ReseedCnt` is set to zero during initializiation.
- When reading the seed file, `ReseedCnt` is untouched.
- When generating random data, `ReseedCnt` is incremented when enough entropy is available in `Pool[0]` and enough time has passed (not the case during first boot).

So, is the paper missing some steps on what to do in this situation? Section 9.6.6 about first boot explicitly states: 'Having an outside source of randomness to create the first seed file is probably the best solution.'

Comment: Looking at **[fortuna.c](http://web.mit.edu/freebsd/head/sys/dev/random/fortuna.c)** (as used in FreeBSD) might help if the pseudo-code confuses you a bit.

Comment: I did, but this check I am talking about is not implemented in the FreeBSD version of Fortuna. But I don't know why, or why I can deviated from that.

Comment: Sounds maybe strange, but we live in a world where the authors of most of the crypto primitives are still alive. You could simply contact Bruce and ask him :) He may not respond to every request of course, but this seems one that might be answered.

Answer (score 2):

You have to appreciate that Bruce and Niels' paper isn't source code. They wrote "*We assume there are several sources of entropy in the environment*" and "*feel free to
choose AES (Rijndael), Serpent, or Twofish for this function*".  It's a bit of a concept paper without a hard implementation.  That's been left to others.

An example of this is on [Silicon Labs micro controllers](https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/application-notes/AN0806.pdf).  That implementation is ultimately seeded with real entropy from reading the internal temperature sensor.  Those tend to jitter somewhat, creating true randomness. Even they though add this proviso: "*The user is encouraged to implement additional entropy
sources.*"  The implementation of FreeBSD palms this off to various device drivers to call the [random_harvest_*()](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=random_harvest&sektion=9&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2011.1-RELEASE%20and%20Ports) function themselves.

This entropy input step is outside of the Fortuna construct. They clearly couldn't predict where Fortuna would be running so it was correct to leave this to particular implementations.  It could easily be avalanche diodes, keyboard key scanning firmware or even the internal temperature sensors that are scattered throughout desktop motherboards these days.